# Steam graphics errors with intel DG1

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, steam, intel

Every time I start steam, whether downloaded on Ubuntu Software or apt, one of the following 2 things happen:
-Steam gets stuck on getting user data
-Steam opens, but you can't see the interface, being able to interact with buttons but all being invisible.

This error is repeated several times in the terminal:

```
DRI3 not available
Failed to load driver: zink
```

This problem still persists even if i follow the steps of: https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/driver/client/overview.html

GPU: Asus DG1-4G (Intel Iris Xe)

Here i left information about my graphics driver:

glxinfo -B

```
name of display: :0
DRI3 not available
failed to load driver: zink
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 24.0.0
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 15862MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 4.5
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 31 MB, largest block: 31 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 13184 MB, largest block: 13184 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 31 MB, largest block: 31 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 13184 MB, largest block: 13184 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 31 MB, largest block: 31 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 13184 MB, largest block: 13184 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 1911813 MB
    Total available memory: 1927675 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 31 MB
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.0.0-devel (git-3ca1f35cbf)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.0-devel (git-3ca1f35cbf)
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.0.0-devel (git-3ca1f35cbf)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

sudo lshw -c video

```
*-display NO RECLAMADO    
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: DG1 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       versión: 01
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: iomemory:400-3ff memoria:a0000000-a0ffffff memoria:4000000000-40ffffffff memoria:a1000000-a11fffff
  *-graphics
       producto: EFI VGA
       id físico: 2
       nombre lógico: /dev/fb0
       capacidades: fb
       configuración: depth=32 resolution=1024,768
```

lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation DG1 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:4908] (rev 01)
```

Steam Log:

```
steam.sh[8421]: Running Steam on ubuntu 22.04 64-bit
steam.sh[8421]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[8491]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[8421]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
tid(8550) burning pthread_key_t == 0 so we never use it
[2024-02-06 14:51:53] Startup - updater built Jan 13 2024 00:51:43
[2024-02-06 14:51:53] Startup - Steam Client launched with: '/home/chaos/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam' '-nominidumps' '-nobreakpad'
02/06 14:51:53 Init: Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1705108172)/tid(8550)
DRI3 not available
failed to load driver: zink
[2024-02-06 14:51:53] Loading cached metrics from disk (/home/chaos/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2024-02-06 14:51:53] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2024-02-06 14:51:53] 1. https://client-update.akamai.steamstatic.com, /, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1000, source = 'update_hosts_cached.vdf'
[2024-02-06 14:51:53] 2. https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'update_hosts_cached.vdf'
[2024-02-06 14:51:53] 3. https://cdn.steamstatic.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2024-02-06 14:51:53] Verifying installation...
[2024-02-06 14:51:54] Verification complete

Steam logging initialized: directory: /home/chaos/.steam/debian-installation/logs

XRRGetOutputInfo Workaround: initialized with override: 0 real: 0xf68ad9c0
XRRGetCrtcInfo Workaround: initialized with override: 0 real: 0xf68ac1f0
/usr/share/themes/Yaru-red-dark/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
/usr/share/themes/Yaru-red-dark/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
DRI3 not available
failed to load driver: zink
DRI3 not available
failed to load driver: zink
steamwebhelper.sh[8677]: Runtime for steamwebhelper: defaulting to /home/chaos/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-heavy
steamwebhelper.sh[8677]: glibc >= 2.34, partially disabling sandbox until CEF supports clone3()
DRI3 not available
failed to load driver: zink
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 31 milliseconds to initialize
DRI3 not available
failed to load driver: zink
Steam Runtime Launch Service: starting steam-runtime-launcher-service
Steam Runtime Launch Service: steam-runtime-launcher-service is running pid 8913
bus_name=com.steampowered.PressureVessel.LaunchAlongsideSteam
DRI3 not available
failed to load driver: zink
BRefreshApplicationsInLibrary 1: 0ms
BuildCompleteAppOverviewChange: 299 apps
RegisterForAppOverview 1: 5ms
RegisterForAppOverview 2: 5ms
```

(At this point Steam executes, but is invisible)

Comment: Zink and "NO RECLAMADO" mean that your GPU wasn't detected. If you're on a recently released GPU, select the 6.5 HWE kernel, or try Ubuntu 23.10 or 24.04.

Comment: Seems like i already have that kernel, and also tried with others like the 5.19 (to install intel dmks), also i my GPU is not recent but it is not very know or supported, and about Ubuntu 23.10, is possible upgrade my Ubuntu to that vercion without loosing data?

Comment: No, 22.04 to 23.10 is not supported. You'll have to wait for 24.04.1. Just try lshw on the 23.10 LiveCD. If you have dkms, you can try uninstalling it

Comment: I tried the intel dkms, but it always gives me errors, so i uninstalled and removed the files, i will try that about the LiveCD

Comment: Lshw in the LiveCD of Ubuntu 23.10 also says UNCLAIMED

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things and researching, I tried again to install the Intel DKMS, where the i915 driver was included, this time it worked and I could access all the graphics functions and make steam work, I can't really say what made it work this time, because before trying that I just installed the intel media driver to the LiveCD to see if it worked.

Before, when I tried to install the DKMS, I got errors that I couldn't process the package, during its own installation and that of other applications separately, and in that case I had to purge all the DKMS to be able to reinstall applications, just before it could be installed it came out that it was already built into the kernel, But I ended up trying to install it again and that's how it worked.

It seems that with this new controller I have more problems, such as it goes black every time a new app is in full screen and I have to disconnect the video cable and reconnect it again.

When i was in Windows, i also had that problem, but it was only on the startup, if anyone have an answer about that, i will appreciate it.

Comment: Depending on your DE, you can try to fix the fullscreen problem by disabling direct scanout in order to force compositing

Comment: Hello, i did not find any information about how to change that setting, seems like it is only on Wayland, and currently i only can use Xorg, i will search more, thanks for the help.